# Wso2 PDP authentication method

Tags: wso2, xacml, pdp

I want to use Wso2 as Policy Decision Point but i dont really like that it uses Basic Auth.

Is it possible to change the authentication method for the XACML requests ? 
Can i use SSO for example?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about changing the authentication methods in WSO2 IS itself, but one option for strong authentication would be to setup and apache or nginx reverse proxy that uses client certificate verification.  The endpoints making the XACML requests would need a certificate signed by a CA that you create, so it would only work if you had a few specific endpoints you wanted to make requests.